# How to solve React rerenderign issue

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, rerender, usecallback, react-usememo

have sum function and sum as dependency of useEffect. whenever the input change console.log("sum is") printed. console.log("sum is") is not printed when there is no dependency in useEffect even if input change. it is because of when input change it rerender the component and sum function address will be assign to different thats why it trigger the useEffect or may be different.

```html
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [num1] = useState(4);
  const [num2] = useState(5);
  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const sum = () => num1 + num2;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("sum is");
  }, [num]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to put `sum` (instead of `num`) in the `useEffect` dependency?

Comment: Sorry that was sum

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is a React hook used to make some kind of co-routines, it is triggered when it dependencies are updated or when the component is rendered

```
// 1. No dependency passed:
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on every render
});
// 2. An empty array:
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs only on the first render
}, []);
// 3. Props or state values:
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on the first render
  //And any time any dependency value changes
}, [prop, state]);
```

Comment: thank u for response. change in input state will trigger useEffect in myCase. m not getting why it behave in this way.

Comment: That was sum not num

Comment: sum never changes, you should put input has useEffect depedency

Answer (score 0):

The reason `console.log("sum is")` is executed on every render is because `sum` is a function and not a value, and when a function is compared to another function, even if its defined exactly the same way, the equality operator will return false

For example:

```
const f1 = () => 1 + 2;
const f2 = () => 1 + 2;
const isEqaul = f1 === f2;
console.log(isEqual); // output is false
```

In your case `const sum = () => num1 + num2` is reassigned with a different value on each render, and `useEffect` identifies that the value of `sum` had changed.

To solve the problem, you can:

1. Define `sum` as a value: `cosnt sum = num1 + num2`
2. Use the `useCallback` hook which is used to memoize the function (in other words, the function will be stored in memory and therefore be equal in each render)

```
const sumCallback = useCallback(
  () => num1 + num2,
  [num1, num2],
);
```

Now, as long as num1 and num2 aren't assigned with new values, `sumCallback` will have the same value each time